# Generate search links for comma separated words

Tags: javascript, list, hyperlink, keyword

as always, your help is very much valued <3

I have listings on my site that feature metadata keywords in the description. I'd like to make these appear like tags (our cms doesn't support tags hence this hack). It prints just the words separated with commas, like so:

```
<div class="tags">abp, accredited building practitioners, calendar of events, upcoming events</div>
```

Is javascript capable of finding any word in these divs and replacing them with a href that links to oursite.com/search?query=THEWORD ? If so, does anyone have a script they can share?

Comment: undated my Answer. This works good in the link [updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working function built with a little jQuery, although easily can be converted to basic JavaScript:

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.tags').each(function(){
            var obj=$(this),tags=obj.text().split(','),i=0,len=tags.length;
            if(obj.text()) {
                for(i;i<len;i++) {
                    var tag=tags[i].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,'');
                    tags[i]='<a href="http://oursite.com/search?query='+encodeURIComponent(tag)+'">'+tag+'</a>';
                }
                obj.html(tags.join(', '));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tags">abp, accredited building practitioners, calendar of events, upcoming events</div>
<div class="tags">test, another test, some more testing, etc</div>
<div class="tags">the, code, needed, to, be , in, an, each(), loop</div>
<div class="tags"></div>
<div class="tags">random, words, that, show, work, hopefully</div>
<div class="tags">the, return, false, was, causing, problems</div>
<div class="tags"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a problem. The div occurs 10 times per page of results. Once for each result. It's duplicating the same tags for every div now, is it possible to make each div independent of each other?

Comment: Sorry about that, just wrap the code in an each() loop; I have updated my answer with the loop included.

Comment: Awesome, it's working perfectly, a huge thank you from me :D small bug where if there are no tags it prints a blank link, as unfortunately the site will still paint the <div class="tags"> divs even when no keywords are present :/

Comment: I never tested this on an empty `DIV`, however I have updated the code with a simple check for text within the `DIV` before attempting to parse the tags.

Comment: Thank you heaps, that's almost working perfectly. It does indeed ignore empty tag divs now, but unfortunately it ignores any tag divs after the empty div too. So tags work great until no tags are present in one div, then for the rest of the page tags display unlinked.

Comment: Ah yes, the `return(false);` was breaking the loop unintended, however that's fixed now. Updated code is above.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out. If the alert msg that you see is what you are looking for than you just need to append it in the div.
http://jsfiddle.net/UH5U9/3/

### EDIT

```
$('.tags').each(function(){
var s = $(this).html()

a = s.split(',');      
var temp='';      
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    temp =temp + '<a href="oursite.com/search?query='+a[i]+'">'+a[i]+'</a>';

 }
$(this).html('');
$(this).html(temp);
});
```

Comment: post your answer here too, not just in the fiddle

Comment: @cloudYturtle I have only basic JS experience, could you pleaseeeee show me how to append it to the divs? :D