# Simple remove text script

Tags: javascript, text

this might be simple, but I've spent ages searching and googling, I've come close, but no cigar...

Is anyone able to whip me up a little script to delete all instances of

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/search?mode=results&amp;queries_name_query="></a>
```

in the body of a HTML doc?

My tags are generated by JS and they always print an extra blank href so hopefully another quick script to remove them can clear this up?

All help and helpful advice is always very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not fix the script that's generating excess instead of cleaning up after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut tells me you probably just want to alter the script that's creating them to prevent it from happening, but if you really can't do that, something like the following should get rid of all of 'em in a quick-'n-dirty kind of way...

```
var badLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='http://mysite.com/search?mode=results&amp;queries_name_query=']");

for (var i=0;i<badLinks.length;i++)
   badLinks[i].parentNode.removeChild(badLinks[i]);
```

Comment: Doesn't this code assume all `a` elements are direct children of the `body` element? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuvuE/).

Comment: Everything but the title and script/css links should be in the body.

Comment: @alex Ah, right you are! I've edited my answer to fix it. Silly me... Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @JKing Thank you :) JS just isn't my area, I've placed the script in the head but unfortunately it's not working. Is there anything I've missed other than the <script></script> tags?

Comment: @Justanotherdunce Any link _should_ be a descendant of the body, you are correct, but what he said/meant was _direct_ children. It's safe to assume that these links will be more distance descendants, and unfortunately `removeChild()` _does_ require a reference to a direct child node (not a grandChild, great-grand, etc...) of the element you're calling it on. It was a stupid mistake on my part that, had I thought about it for a second, I should have caught.

Comment: @user1038627 you've gotta make sure it runs _after_ the links get added to the body. Since the links are being generated by another JS file (and I don't know when that one executes) it's a little tricky to tell when you should run it. Maybe stick in in a timeout? Again, this is getting into _really_ dirty/hacky territory. If you want to email me your code or something I can take a closer look, but back&forth chats in comments is supposedly frowned upon...

Comment: @JKing thanks :) The code to build the links is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022781 - If I can get your email address, that would be awesome :D Thank you!

Comment: @user1038627 Ah, that would have been helpful! It looks like the problem is just that it's dying when it encounters an empty div? that's 'cause of that if/else in there. If it's not empty it runs the if block, else it's returning (breaking the loop) so, just remove the `else{return(false);}` and it should just do nothing when it encounters an empty div, and then keep looping. If that doesn't do it, you can find my email on my profile page.

Comment: @JKing Thanks heaps mate :) That's stopped blank divs appearing as empty hrefs! I still get an empty href at the end of lists of tags though in populated .tag divs. I've checked your profile, and I can't find your email anywhere, perhaps it's blanked out by default for n00b users like me to stop you getting bombarded?

Comment: @user1038627 Is it happening consistently? Is there always 1 extra empty link at the end of a sting of "real" links? is there maybe an extra comma being added accidentally? It's hard to say without the whole source/context. I dunno why you can't see my email though... It's jking@perforce.com

Comment: Thanks :) I've sent you an email! Some amazing people on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

```
function cleanlinks(){
  var tem, s="http://mysite.com/search?mode=results&amp;queries_name_query=",
  L=document.links, len=L.length;
  while(len){
    tem=L[--len];
    if(tem.href===s)tem.parentNode.removeChild(tem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mode=results&amp;queries_name_query=` could get dynamic, you can match the previous part by:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName(a);
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {  
  if(anchors[i].getAttribute('href').match('http://mysite.com/search?mode=results&amp;queries_name_query=') !== -1) {
       anchors[i].parentNode.removeChild(anchors[i]);
   }
}
```